# Powershell script to create folders from CSV list of users

Tags: permissions, scripting, powershell

I found a powershell script that creates folders (if they dont exist) and adds appropriate permissions.
Below is the PS1 file (created by someone else)

---

```
##################################################################################
#
#
#  Script name: SetFolderPermission.ps1
#  Author:      goude@powershell.nu
#  Homepage:    www.powershell.nu
#
#
##################################################################################

param ([string]$Path, [string]$Access, [string]$Permission = ("Modify"), [switch]$help)

function GetHelp() {

$HelpText = @"

DESCRIPTION:
NAME: SetFolderPermission.ps1
Sets FolderPermissions for User on a Folder.
Creates folder if not exist.

PARAMETERS: 
-Path           Folder to Create or Modify (Required)
-User           User who should have access (Required)
-Permission     Specify Permission for User, Default set to Modify (Optional)
-help           Prints the HelpFile (Optional)

SYNTAX:
./SetFolderPermission.ps1 -Path C:\Folder\NewFolder -Access Domain\UserName -Permission FullControl

Creates the folder C:\Folder\NewFolder if it doesn't exist.
Sets Full Control for Domain\UserName

./SetFolderPermission.ps1 -Path C:\Folder\NewFolder -Access Domain\UserName

Creates the folder C:\Folder\NewFolder if it doesn't exist.
Sets Modify (Default Value) for Domain\UserName

./SetFolderPermission.ps1 -help

Displays the help topic for the script

Below Are Available Values for -Permission

"@
$HelpText

[system.enum]::getnames([System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights])

}

function CreateFolder ([string]$Path) {

    # Check if the folder Exists

    if (Test-Path $Path) {
        Write-Host "Folder: $Path Already Exists" -ForeGroundColor Yellow
    } else {
        Write-Host "Creating $Path" -Foregroundcolor Green
        New-Item -Path $Path -type directory | Out-Null
    }
}

function SetAcl ([string]$Path, [string]$Access, [string]$Permission) {

    # Get ACL on FOlder

    $GetACL = Get-Acl $Path

    # Set up AccessRule

    $Allinherit = [system.security.accesscontrol.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"
    $Allpropagation = [system.security.accesscontrol.PropagationFlags]"None"
    $AccessRule = New-Object system.security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Access, $Permission, $AllInherit, $Allpropagation, "Allow")

    # Check if Access Already Exists

    if ($GetACL.Access | Where { $_.IdentityReference -eq $Access}) {

        Write-Host "Modifying Permissions For: $Access" -ForeGroundColor Yellow

        $AccessModification = New-Object system.security.AccessControl.AccessControlModification
        $AccessModification.value__ = 2
        $Modification = $False
        $GetACL.ModifyAccessRule($AccessModification, $AccessRule, [ref]$Modification) | Out-Null
    } else {

        Write-Host "Adding Permission: $Permission For: $Access"

        $GetACL.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
    }

    Set-Acl -aclobject $GetACL -Path $Path

    Write-Host "Permission: $Permission Set For: $Access" -ForeGroundColor Green
}

if ($help) { GetHelp }

if ($Path -AND $Access -AND $Permission) { 
    CreateFolder $Path 
    SetAcl $Path $Access $Permission
}
```

---

To run this script I use this command.
./SetFolderPermission.ps1 -Path E:\TestFolder\UsernameX -Access Domain\UsernameX -Permission modify

How can I make it so that i can just use one command and call it to create the folders from a CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:-

```
# Read in List of Users
$ListofUsers=Get-Content "UserList.csv"
foreach ($User in $ListofUsers)
{
SetFolderPermission.ps1 -Path E:\TestFolder\$User
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would modify Gary's command slightly, and use Import-Csv

```
# Read in List of Users
$rows=Import-Csv "UserList.csv"
foreach ($row in $rows) {
  $UsernameX = $row.UserName
  ./SetFolderPermission.ps1 -Path E:\TestFolder\$UsernameX -Access Domain\$UsernameX -Permission modify
}
```